# How would I add a prefix to input I receive from a pipe via awk and color the prefix conditionally?

Tags: shell-script, awk, colors

Is there a way to add a prefix to lines received (and filtered) via `awk` - yes I know *that's* possible so far - and then conditionally (e.g. based on the existence of the `$PS1` variable of the surrounding Bash script or `[ -t 1 ]`) color it using ANSI escape sequences?

I know how to add a prefix using the `^` anchor and about two or three other ways and I know how to use escape sequences in Bash `echo` and `printf`.

How - if at all - can I color the output produced by `awk` as outlined, based on a condition that can be evaluated inside an inline `awk` script?

NB: I have `mawk` or `gawk` at my disposal, `mawk` is default.

Comment: It seems that scripts don't have `PS1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  eval "$(printf 'COLOR_ON="\033[31m" COLOR_OFF="\033[m"')"
else
  COLOR_ON= COLOR_OFF=
fi
export COLOR_ON COLOR_OFF
awk '{print ENVIRON["COLOR_ON"] "prefix: " ENVIRON["COLOR_OFF"] $0}'
```

Or:

```
[ ! -t 1 ]
awk -v color="$?" '{
   print((color ? "\033[31m" : "") "prefix: " (color ? "\033[m" : "") $0)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a terminal this way:

```
> echo foo | awk '{if (system("tty >/dev/null 2>&1")) print "true"; else print "false";}'
true
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the first part. Alas, the awk output does not seem to interpret escape sequences. So to output for example a green `true`, the escape sequence gets blurted out verbatim (`"\033[1;32mtrue\033[0m"`), where the outer quoting uses single quotes as in your example. Unfortunately `echo` takes no input from stdin, so appending `|echo -e` doesn't work (neither with `/bin/echo`).

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done` ?

Comment: On another note, your example always gives me `false` as output and the `not a tty` actually ends up on the terminal. The while read might do the job, `cat -` also does I just found out. Running `tty` standalone in the same terminal I run your command in, yields `/dev/pts/7`, so this method may have some dependencies. Did you use `gawk` or `mawk`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Did you copy & paste my code?

Comment: yes, otherwise I couldn't be sure it's the same. Btw; the `while read` works just the same as `cat -`, but a clever way of getting `echo` in there. Hadn't though of it. +1 for all your time so far.

Comment: @0xC0000022L What happens if you call `tty; tty &>/dev/null` directly in the script?

Comment: `tty &>/dev/null` is not POSIX. Well it is, but it means run `tty` in background and truncate `/dev/null` (same as `tty & > /dev/null`). That's `bash` syntax, you should not use it in `system()` which spawns the system's `sh`. Use `tty > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Note that `tty` checks if there's a controlling terminal, not if stdout is a terminal (well in this case, `tty`'s stdout is `/dev/null` anyway).